# code not able to compile code in VS 2008 but works fine in 2003

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I have variable initialized as

```
OvXplBase::UTF16Char_t const *qName
```

and when I simply use strlen as `(strlen(qName)+1))`;  this code gives an error as

> "cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const OvXplBase::UTF16Char_t *' to
>   'const wchar_t *'"

just explicitly typecasting qname  to (tchar *) in VS 2008, do compile but it throws run time error as 
"access violation reading memory" after some time.

This code works perfectly in 2003 , I have tried doing all kind of unicode settings in VS 2008. So can you all guide me, what else I can do to make this piece of code working.

or how should I convert this UTF16Char_t * to wchar_t* so that this code runs perfectly.

Regards,
Geek

Comment: Can you include a definition of `UTF16Char_t`?

Comment: it is 
typedef UInt16_t  UTF16Char_t

typedef unsigned short UInt16_t

Comment: Hi JaredPar,

How Can I convert this UInt16_t to tchar* so that, it is well written in memory and it doesn't give any run time error?????